# Is it possible to overwrite a CSS class defined previously in Odoo?

Tags: css, odoo, odoo-10

I need to change the class `page`, which you can see in every report template.

This does what I want:

```
<div class="page" style="margin-left: 7mm">
   ...
</div>
```

The problem is that I need to apply that style each time the class `page` is applied, so it would be very useful for me if I was able to modify the class to add my `margin-left`. If not, I guess I will have to change every template which has `class="page"` inside, which will be awful.

May be you're wondering why I need to add that `margin-left`, that's because I have to add a text on the left margin of every page, so I have to add a div in the header. The problem is that if you try to write inside the margin (out of the `div class="page"`), this text dissapears due to the left margin of the paperformat. So I set this paperformat margin to 0. After this I had to move the header and the footer 7mm to the right, which was easy. The problem is that I also need to move the content of the report 7mm to the right, and that's why I'm trying to modify the class `page`.

If anyone knows how to do that or finds a better solution for my issue, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Could you provide an image with the result you want to get?

Comment: You can add one custom class through js and from that custom added class you add your css for that too. In your case add custom class to `.page` class and then apply css to your added class. Might that will work.

Answer (score 4):

To inherit and modify an existing CSS class, this worked for me:

```
<template id="my_custom_style_modifications" inherit_id="report.layout">
    <xpath expr="//style" position="after">
        <style type="text/css">                   
            .page {
                margin-left: 7mm;
            }                    
        </style>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

**EDIT**

Well, I needed to do this again and I was wondering why I had set my solution as the right one since it did not work for me this time (it threw me the error that `style` was not found in parent view)... something must have changed, I guess. This time I had to do the following to achieve my purpose (however, this solution only works if the report is printed in HTML format, not in PDF -still looking for something to fix that-):

```
<template id="aus_custom_reports_style_modifications" inherit_id="report.layout">
    <xpath expr="//html" position="before">
        <style type="text/css">                   
            .page {
                margin-left: 7mm;
            }                    
        </style>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

First if you want to change css in report don't add the css file to backend assets
you should add it to report assets:

```xml
  <template id="assets_common" name="add css for page class" inherit_id="report.assets_common">
```

just to make sure that the css is applied and to make sure that this technique it's not
working as expected add a border to the page or change background color and css if your
css is applied.

Now if this technique is not working it will be better if you provide a picture or explain
what you need exactly may be there is a better way to do it.

**Note** don't forget to add dependency for report addon in your manifest file.

Comment: this technique will not work i think your code will be ignored by  wkhtmltopdf so can you explain what you want again

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Cherif, My purpose was to write a text vertically inside the margin-left of each page of every report. That was the issue, but I've found the response to the main question: How to inherit and modify a CSS class made in other module.

Comment: so you need something like header but in the left margin?

Comment: Exactly, in fact, finally I've modified the header in a weird way to manage that.

Answer (score 0):

Its working like this:

Write margin in CSS file

HTML

```
   <div class="page">
       ...
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.page{margin-left:7mm !important}
```

Comment: Hi @Nirmal, that's the first thing I tried, I made a CSS file in my module and added it to the assets backend. Inside the CSS file I wrote `.page{margin-left:7mm}` but it didn't work.

Comment: Try with the `!important` keyword: `.page{margin-left:7mm !important}`

Comment: Try with important tag: .page{margin-left:7mm !important}

Comment: It doesn't work, it seems that whatever I write in the class `.page` of my module doesn't affect to the original `.page` class.